# Converting a function pointer into a delegate cause a problem?

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, function-pointers, com-interop

I am using C# dll in C++ code by using COM Interop. Now I am Passing a function pointer to C# dll where the function pointer is converted to Delegate by using

```
Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer()
```

Now my question is "What are possibilities are for unexpected behavior here ?"  and what are problems in converting function pointer into a Delegate

Comment: well, i wouldn't do that myself, if i could possibly avoid it. but are you actually experiencing problems? and if so, what?

Comment: No I am not experiencing any issues.. But i just need to conform that was legal or not

Comment: That function will work correctly if you've been really careful about matching the delegate definition to the native function type, including calling convention.  It's pretty simple to use.  The reverse function is a lot more dangerous because you have to worry about the garbage collector.

Comment: That said, with COM it's very rare to be dealing in function pointers.  Usually you will pass pointer to a COM object and access its methods through virtual member function calls.